# i want my second combobox not show the selecteditem from the first one

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

Hallo i have one combo box and i fill it from my database, the combo box is showing me ofc all the values from my db. Now i have one more combo box after this one and i want not to showing me the Selected Item from the first one. How i can archive this one?

View:

```
  <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" IsEditable="False"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding combo}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding selectedTeam}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemp}" />
```

I Tried it the second one to bind it also in the same Observer able collection and to use an Converter that it ***returns value.Visibility.Hidden;*** , but it did not worked.

////////////// UPDATE 1 ///////////////////////

Hallo and thanks a lot for the answer, i have tried your method but now i cannot see on the two comboboxes not the selecteditem...

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
DataContext="{Binding ComboFilterCollection}"
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemp}" />
```

myviewModel:

```
public TestClassVM SelectedItem { get{ return _SelectedItem; }
set { _SelectedItem = value;
OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");

if ( _SelectedItem != null )
{
ICollectionView ComboFilterCollection = CollectionViewSource.GEtDefaultView(combo);
ComboFilterCollection.Filter = (i) => i != SelectedItem;
ComboFilterCollection.Refresh();
}
else
...
}

public ICollectionView ComboFilterCollection
{ get { return _ComboFilterCollection;}
  set { _ComboFilterCollection = value;
OnPropertyChanged("ComboFilterCollection");}}
```

Now when i select something on my first combo box I cannot see the selected value on the two combo boxes... but how can that be possible? I tried different methods but it just did not worked out...

Someone can have a further idea of what is happening would be appreciated, thanks in advance guys!

Comment: In `ItemsSource="{Binding combo}"` what is `combo`? Is it your first combo box?

Comment: This is my first combo box and combo is an Observer able collection

Comment: Where is the code for your second ComboBox?

Comment: Is the same code i want the second combo box to show exactly the same except the selected item from the first one man. I don't want to fill a new list one more time because this take time and also is eating services from my PC...

Answer (score 0):

ICollectionView is your choice

here is an example for you

I added property `combo2` of type ICollectionView and added `OnSelectedTeamChange` to selectedTeam, assuming combo has the data.

```
   public ICollectionView combo2
    {
        get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(combo2Property); }
        set { SetValue(combo2Property, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for combo2.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty combo2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("combo2", typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(View), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public object selectedTeam
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(selectedTeamProperty); }
        set { SetValue(selectedTeamProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for selectedTeam.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty selectedTeamProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("selectedTeam", typeof(object), typeof(View), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedTeamChange));
```

initialized the collection view and added filter to filter out the selectedTeam from the source

```
    public void InitView()
    {
        combo2 = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(combo);
        combo2.Filter = (i) => i != selectedTeam;
    }
```

added OnSelectedTeamChange method to refresh the collection view when selectedTeam changes

```
    public static void OnSelectedTeamChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as View).combo2.Refresh();
    }
```

now you can bind this combo2 to your second combo which will have all the items but selectedTeam

Comment: does it mean that the solution does not work or you want more clarification?